# search for tracking script in site using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have just starting to play around with selenium, so this may be a bit of a noob question. One of my co-workers has to check around 100 pages of our site to see if there is a tracking script inserted on it. She has to do this once a month, hence my decision to research selenium.

Currently, she goes to the page looks at source and searches for this (and other script tracking functions)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssltracking.esearchvision.com/esi/trackingtest.js"></script>
```

Some of the pages include forms that need to be filled and submitted. I figure out how to set values of dom elements using the selenium IDE easily enough.

What I am unsure how to do is tell selenium to search for this script inside the source code. I am fine with installing selenium webdriver on our server if that is needed. I haven't program in Java, C# or Python before but I do have node.js installed along with php of course.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to scrape the source code off the web-page. Then somehow beautify it and finally search for the script tag. I would recommend Ruby as a programming language and the nokogiri gem as the easiest way to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

In python, using the selenium element locators as opposed to string matching:

```
from selenium import selenium
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver = webdriver.Firefox() ## or whatever browser you prefer
driver.get("yourpage.com")
## wait for page to load
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('script') )
scripts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('script')

for script in scripts:
    if( script.get_attribute('src') == \
        'https://ssltracking.esearchvision.com/esi/trackingtest.js' and \
        script.get_attribute('type') == 'text/javascript' ):
        ## do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
String trackingScript = "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssltracking.esearchvision.com/esi/trackingtest.js"></script>"

String html = driver.getPageSource();
if (html.indexOf(trackingScript) != -1) {
    // the script is in the page source
}
else {
    // the script is not in the page source
}
```

Comment: string matching may not be very robust, i think using the element locators would be preferable